# The set $A=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove that the set $A=\{(x, y, z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq 4\}$ is closed,  to do this give me any point $p=(a, b, c)\in A^c$ and define $$r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-2=||(a, b, c)-(0, 0, c)||-2$$ I note that $B_r(p)\subseteq A^c$ but that's what I can not prove algebraically. Help me prove that if $(x, y, z)\in B_r(p)$ then $x^2+y^2>4$.

Consider the usual distance between points $||(a, b, c)-(x, y, z)||=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2}$.

Thanks.

Comment: I need prove the exercise using the definition of closed set.

Comment: You listed this as general topology -- what is your definition of a closed set -- that the complement is open?  That seems to be what you want to use, based on the proof direction you want to go with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $(a', b', c') \in B_r(p)$. We need to determine whether or not this point is in $A$.  This is the same as determining whether $\sqrt{{a'}^2+{b'}^2} \leq 2$. But $\sqrt{{a'}^2+{b'}^2} > \sqrt{a^2+b^2}-r=2$. (This last part follows from the fact that the largest change to $\sqrt{{a'}^2+{b'}^2}$ comes if $c'=c$ and then $r>||(a',b',c)-(a,b,c)|| =||(a',b',0)-(a,b,0)|| \geq ||(a,b,0)||-||(a',b',0)||$)

Comment: It's intuitively obvious that "the largest change to...comes if $c' = c$.  However if OP wants a totally rigorous proof then that sub-claim needs proof.

Comment: Good point. Ok, so we want to find the situation when $\sqrt{{a'}^2+{b'}^2}$ is maximized for a fixed distance $||(a,b,c)-(a',b',c')||$. Given any tuple $(a',b',c')$ I will show that I can find a tuple $(a'', b'', 0)$ where $\sqrt{{a''}^2+{b''}^2} \geq \sqrt{{a'}^2+{b'}^2}$ and $||(a,b,c)-(a',b',c')||=||(a,b,c)-(a'',b'',c'')||$. Simply let $a''=a', c''=0$ and modify $b''$ by an amount $\epsilon$ so that $|b''|-|b'|=\epsilon$ and $(b-b'')^2=(b-b')^2+(c-c')^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know the following fact (If not, first prove it from your definition) : A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is closed iff for any sequence $(a_n) \in A$, if $a_n \to a$, then $a \in A$.

So suppose $a_n = (x_n, y_n, z_n) \in A$ such that $a_n \to a = (x,y,z)$. Then
$$
x_n^2 + y_n^2 \leq 4
$$
Also, $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$, hence
$$
x_n^2 + y_n^2 \to x^2 + y^2
$$
Hence, it follows that $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$, and so $a \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Triangle inequality implies $$\lVert a-b\rVert + \lVert b\rVert \ge \lVert a\rVert$$